# JAVA - get class from file.java located on disk

Tags: java, load, classloader, disk

I want to load class definitions or fields from file.java located on disk.
I tried URLClassLoader:

```java
URL url = file.toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class c = new Object().getClass();
try {
    c = cl.loadClass(className);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    System.err.println("not found class: " + className);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The `.java` file needs to be compiled to a `.class` file first...

Comment: what are you expecting it to do? and what error does it give ? where do you define or give it className ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java example with ClassLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691855/java-example-with-classloader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load classes via `loadClass`, but not source code files. `.java` files contain *source code*. With Java, as with many (but not all) other languages, you must "compile" the source code into a machine-readable form — in the case of Java, a `.class` file (which may or may not then be bundled into a `.jar`). You compile Java code with the `javac` tool (or the features of your IDE).

For instance, if you have a class called `Foo` defined in a file called `Foo.java`, then:

```
javac Foo.java
```

...will create `Foo.class`, which can then be loaded.

You may find [this "Getting Started": The "Hello World" application tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) useful. It goes through the steps of getting the tools set up on your computer, writing a source file, compiling it into a class file, and running it.

Comment: Thank you, it works after compilation. But when the file have imports there are errors during compilation.